# React context state value not updated in Consumer

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

The first value set to "search term" through the "dispatcher" persists after any subsequent calls and I'm trying to figure out why that is or where the error is.

I've got a `<ContextProvider />` where a state for "search term" is defined, and the value for the "search term" might change by an event that is triggered by the `<ContextConsumer />`, or nested `<ContextConsumer />` component by a "dispatcher". I'm finding that the desired state is not found, after the call to the "reducer", even considering that the "state" change is not immediately.

For brevity, the Components or the code posted below was simplified to isolate the subject, so there might be a few typos like not declared variables (as I've removed chunks of code that is not related).

The Context Provider looks like:

```
import React from 'react'

export const POSTS_SEARCH_RESULTS = 'POSTS_SEARCH_RESULTS'

export const GlobalStateContext = React.createContext()
export const GlobalDispatchContext = React.createContext()

const initialState = {
  posts: [],
  searchTerm: ''
}

const reducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case POSTS_SEARCH_RESULTS: {
      return {
        ...state,
        posts: action.posts,
        searchTerm: action.searchTerm
      }
    }

    default:
      throw new Error('Bad Action Type')
  }
}

const GlobalContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [state, dispatch] = React.useReducer(reducer, initialState)
  return (
    <GlobalStateContext.Provider value={state}>
      <GlobalDispatchContext.Provider value={dispatch}>
        {children}
      </GlobalDispatchContext.Provider>
    </GlobalStateContext.Provider>
  )
}

export default GlobalContextProvider
```

The Consumer looks like:

```
const Search = () => {
  const state = useContext(GlobalStateContext)
  const { searchTerm, posts } = state

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('[debug] <Search />: searchTerm: ', searchTerm);
  }, [searchTerm])

  return (  
     <>
       <LoadMoreScroll searchTerm={searchTerm} posts={posts} postCursor={postCursor} />
     </>

  )
}

export default Search
```

Following up is the nested Consumer Children Component. The `useEffect` has a dependency for `searchTerm`; This value is set through the "dispatcher" and get through the useContenxt in a Consumer.

```
dispatch({ type: POSTS_SEARCH_RESULTS, posts: postsCached, searchTerm: term })
```

And consumed like so:

```
  const state = useContext(GlobalStateContext)
  const { searchTerm, posts } = state
```

And passed to, for example `<LoadMoreScroll searchTerm={searchTerm} />`

So, what I have and it fails is:

```
const LoadMoreScroll = ({ searchTerm, posts, postCursor }) => {
  const dispatch = useContext(GlobalDispatchContext)
  const [postsCached, setPostsCached] = useState(posts)
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)
  const refScroll = useRef(null)
  const [first] = useState(POSTS_SEARCH_INITIAL_NUMBER)
  const [after, setAfter] = useState(postCursor)
  const [isVisible, setIsVisible] = useState(false)
  const [term, setTerm] = useState(searchTerm)

  useEffect(() => {
    loadMore({ first, after, term })
  }, [isVisible])

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch({ type: POSTS_SEARCH_RESULTS, posts: postsCached, searchTerm })
  }, [postsCached])

  useEffect(() => {
    setTerm(searchTerm)
    const handler = _debounce(handleScroll, 1200)
    window.addEventListener('scroll', handler)
    return () => window.removeEventListener('scroll', handler)
  }, [searchTerm])

  const handleScroll = () => {
    const offset = -(window.innerHeight * 0.1)
    const top = refScroll.current.getBoundingClientRect().top
    const isVisible = (top + offset) >= 0 && (top - offset) <= window.innerHeight
    isVisible && setIsVisible(true)
  }

  const loadMore = async ({ first, after, term }) => {
    if (loading) return
    setLoading(true)

    const result = await searchFor({
      first,
      after,
      term
    })

    const nextPosts = result.data

    setPostsCached([...postsCached, ...nextPosts])
    setAfter(postCursor)
    setLoading(false)
    setIsVisible(false)
  }

  return (
    <div ref={refScroll} className={style.loaderContainer}>
      { loading && <Loader /> }
    </div>
  )
}

export default LoadMoreScroll
```

The expected result is to have `<LoadMoreScroll />`'s to pass to the "loadMore" function the latest value of "searchTerm" assigned by the "dispatcher", which fails. What it does instead is that it consumes the "initial value" from a first call to the "dispatcher". This is after the initial call to the "dispatcher" any subsequent "dispatcher" call:

```
dispatch({ type: POSTS_SEARCH_RESULTS, posts: postsCached, searchTerm: term })
```

That should update the Context "searchTerm", fails to do. In the source code above, the loadmore holds the initial value that was set!

Separate example the has a similar logic, works without any issues ( https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-booth-1w40e?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark )

Hope to update the issue above with a solution soon, in case somebody spots the issue, please let me know!

Comment: Can you elaborate your issue? Is it re-render issue? Or is the app crashing on state change? What is the exact issue?

Answer (score 2):

The codesandbox link works, but doesn't seem to be using the same pattern as the code above when it comes to creating and using `context`.

In the provided code you have created two separate providers. One has a value of state and one has a value of dispatch.

```
  <GlobalStateContext.Provider value={state}>
      <GlobalDispatchContext.Provider value={dispatch}>
```

The codesandbox however is using both `state` and `dispatch` within the same `provider`.

```
 <Application.Provider value={{ state, dispatch }}>
```

Also it seems that `GlobalContextProvider` is exported, but I'm not sure if it is used to wrap any consumers.

Since there is a separation of `dispatch` and `state`, I am going to use this for my proposed solution.

The implementation seems correct, but in my opinion you could take this a step further and create two custom hooks, that expose only one way to provide the context value and only one way to consume it.

```
import React from "react";

export const POSTS_SEARCH_RESULTS = "POSTS_SEARCH_RESULTS";

// 
// notice that we don't need to export these anymore as we are going to be 
//
// using them in our custom hooks useGlobalState and useGlobalDispatch
//
//
const GlobalStateContext = React.createContext();
const GlobalDispatchContext = React.createContext();

const initialState = {
  posts: [],
  searchTerm: "",
};

const reducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case POSTS_SEARCH_RESULTS: {
      return {
        ...state,
        posts: action.posts,
        searchTerm: action.searchTerm
      };
    }

    default:
      throw new Error("Bad Action Type");
  }
};

const GlobalContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [state, dispatch] = React.useReducer(reducer, initialState);
  return (
    <GlobalStateContext.Provider value={state}>
      <GlobalDispatchContext.Provider value={dispatch}>
        {children}
      </GlobalDispatchContext.Provider>
    </GlobalStateContext.Provider>
  );
};


// If any of these hooks is not being called within a function component 
// that is rendered within the `GlobalContextProvider`, 
// we throw an error

const useGlobalState = () => {
  const context = React.useContext(GlobalStateContext);
  if (context === undefined) {
    throw new Error(
      "useGlobalState must be used within a GlobalContextProvider"
    );
  }
  return context;
};

const useGlobalDispatch = () => {
  const context = React.useContext(GlobalDispatchContext);
  if (context === undefined) {
    throw new Error(
      "useGlobalDispatch must be used within a GlobalContextProvider"
    );
  }
  return context;
};

// We only export the custom hooks for state and dispatch 
// and of course our`GlobalContextProvider`, which we are 
// going to wrap any part of our app that 
// needs to make use of this state

export { GlobalContextProvider, useGlobalState, useGlobalDispatch };
```

All I've added here is a couple of custom hooks that expose each of the contexts, i.e `GlobalStateContext` and `GlobalDispatchContext` and export them along with the `GlobalContextProvider`.

If we wanted to make this globally available throughout the app, we could wrap the `GlobalContextProvider` around the `App` component.

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Search />
    </div>
  );
}

// If you forget to wrap the consumer with your provider, the custom hook will 
// throw an error letting you know that the hook is not being called 
// within a function component that is rendered within the 
// GlobalContextProvider as it's supposed to

const AppContainer = () => (
  <GlobalContextProvider>
    <App />
  </GlobalContextProvider>
);

export default AppContainer;
```

If you want to either use the `state` in any part of your app, or `dispatch` any action, you will need to import the relevant custom hook created earlier.

In your Search component this would look like the example below:

```
import { useGlobalState, useGlobalDispatch } from "./Store";

const Search = () => {

  // Since we are doing this in our custom hook that is not needed anymore
  // const state = useContext(GlobalStateContext)
  // if you need to dispatch any actions you can 
  // import the useGlobalDispatch hook and use it like so: 
  // const dispatch = useGlobalDispatch();


   const state = useGlobalState(); 
   const { searchTerm, posts } = state

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('[debug] <Search />: searchTerm: ', searchTerm);
  }, [searchTerm])

  return (  
     <>
       <LoadMoreScroll searchTerm={searchTerm} posts={posts} postCursor={postCursor} />
     </>

  )
}

export default Search
```

Since there were a few parts missing in the codesandbox provided in the question, I've refactored it to a simplified working version of this concept [here](https://codesandbox.io/embed/vigorous-field-9v5ix?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark) that hopefully will help solve your issue.

I've also found [this article](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/how-to-use-react-context-effectively) quite helpful when I had problems with Context API and hooks.

It is following that same pattern, I've been using this in production and have been quite happy with the results.

Hope that helps :)